# How do I receive this intent bundle from an appwidgetprovider? Example inside

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onclick, android-appwidget

This is my getViewAt from my RemoteViewsService.  I need to get the position of the row clicked here and use it to send a specific url that is contained in a string array. The reason for this is so i can launch that url when the listview on the appwidget is clicked (simple bookmark widget).

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position){

    RemoteViews row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_list_item);
    row.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetlisttextview,NicknamesW.get(position));
    Intent i = new Intent();
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    extras.putString("getrow",URLSW.get(position));
    i.putExtras(extras);

    row.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widgetlisttextview,i);
```

not sure if i'm missing something here or not but that's what i have so far.

Then here is my appwidgetprovider where i'm trying to finish the onclickIntent and launch the URL.

```
public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {




    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        String teststr = "http://www.dummy.ca";

        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(ctxt,ListViewService.class);
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetIds[i]);
        //
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        //
        RemoteViews widget = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
        widget.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.WidgetListView,svcIntent);

        // set url
        Intent openurl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(teststr));

        PendingIntent clickPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt,0,openurl,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.WidgetListView,clickPI);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],widget);
```

Right now it's just launching the dummy URL from the string teststr.

Any help would be extremely appreciated, I may be taking the wrong approach or just not receiving the intent properly i'm not sure but i'm not sure where to go next.  I don't know where the bundled intent ends up but the onclick is working with the dummy url.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

This is what i've done so far.

// Added action to my androidmanifest "com.halls.jon.LaunchURL" in my AppWidgetProvider receiver and a default Intent category. Just trying to learn how to do this.

```
<receiver android:name=".LinksWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="com.halls.jon.LaunchURL"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/my_widget_provider"/>
    </receiver>
```

// Then i went over to my AppWidgetProvider and changed some of the intent and pending intent. Here is the Code:

```
Intent launch = new Intent("com.halls.jon.LaunchURL");
PendingIntent clickPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt,0,launch,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.WidgetListView,clickPI);
```

// And this is the code i wrote for my onReceive in my AppWidgetProvider.

```
Bundle getdata = intent.getExtras();
    if (getdata != null) {
        String URLLaunch = getdata.getString("url");
        Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URLLaunch));
        context.startActivity(launch);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
```

My app is crashing as soon as i try to drop a widget.  Not sure why. Any further help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the click pending Intent go to a `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest (it could even be your `AppWidgetProvider`) with a custom action. When you receive this action, check the extras and build the actual url, and then call `context.startActivity()`.

Comment: I really appreciate the response, any chance I can get some example code of how that works i'm fairly new.  If not no worries I still appreciate it and i'll look into how to implement your suggestion.  I tried a broadcast receiver once but I must have done it wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: I upvoted your response but it doesn't show up because i'm new and don't have 15 rep yet.  Thanks again i'm glad i have some direction now.

Comment: When I try to set my AppWidgetProvider as a receiver in my manifest I get an error that it has no default constructor. NEVERMIND i'm an idiot i got that to work.

Comment: I'm part way there I think my error is in the manifest and receiving the action.

this is my AppWidgetProvider OnReceive.

`public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle getdata = intent.getExtras();
        String URLLaunch = getdata.getString("url");
        Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URLLaunch));
        context.startActivity(launch);

        super.onReceive(context, intent);`

i'm not quite sure how to tell the manifext that this is the receiver.

Comment: this is my attempt at the receiver in the manifest by the way.


`<receiver android:name=".LinksWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/my_widget_provider"/>
        </receiver>`

Comment: the part i'm missing is the custom action and receiving the action, i'll look do some searching on it, i'm just adding comments to my process for other people struggling if nothing else.

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution and edited my question with the code, if you could tell me where I went wrong that would be great.  Thanks in advance if you get a chance to do that.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I FIGURED IT OUT... literally it took me 2 hours but I got it working i couldn't even find a good example. I had to use a different class as a receiver though.  Using the AppWidgetProvider wasn't working for reasons i'm unsure of.  I think the OnReceive works differently because it can't extend Broadcast Receiver.  I had to seperate them.  Thanks again you pointed me in the right direction even though i had to do most of the legwork I couldn't have done it without you, plus it's my app so that doesn't bother me at all and it's very satisfying that I got it eventually. THANKS